# How to display images & videos in full screen like TIKTOK APP using angular ionic 4 with capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Hi i am learning Angular ionic 4 with capacitor ,my requirement is to Display images & videos in full screen like TIKTOK APP using Angular ionic 4 with capacitor.
If any one have done this previously please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

[Moust Cordova](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer) seems to do exactly what you ask.

Install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-video-player
```

Then simply play the video

```
VideoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4");
```

Comment: i need to play videos using dynamic links like TIKTOK app, its means so many videos then how it is possible by using videoplayer.play()

Comment: By passing a variable, like `VideoPlayer.play(VIDEO_URL)`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , But i am looking for the solution in html file like angular not in ts file